# I got error when integrate log in into Window using Firebase in Android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am doing log in with window account using firebase, i got the error of

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Error getting access token from microsoft.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://App-name.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

I gave the firebase handler url into Azure portal in Redirect URI.
But i am getting this error still.
I am stuck.
Can anybody help me to identify this issue?